# java.util.PropertyPermission when a applet error occurs

Tags: java, security, applet, policyfiles

I am writing a Java applet to implement BT streaming and some kind of errors occurs.

Following is the Java error details:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.bu6ido.bitpower.common.CommonUtils.getSettingsPath(CommonUtils.java:31)
    at MainFrame.TestFrame.loadSettings(TestFrame.java:326)
    at MainFrame.TestFrame.<init>(TestFrame.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I did check twice my `java.policy` file, and also make sure they have:

```
"permission java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read";"
```

But access was still denied. Should I avoid  using user's absolute path or try to set a permission and register something?

Comment: *"I did check twice my java.policy file.."*  The applet will need to be digitally signed before deployment, making the policy file redundant.  So you might as well do that now and stop mucking about with the policy file.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I try to implenment video streaming on html by P2P download,a senior suggest me to use applet,I was asked teacher aboout this,but the teacher said I should keep study that how to fix problems like that.

Comment: So digitally sign the code and get on with it.

Comment: BTW - now that policy file entry is code formatted it seems to have stray characters at the end of it.  Notably `;"`..

Comment: thanks for ur help,I did signed my applet .
but the details show me that the ClassLoader didn't find the main applet.
is that because wrong location of my class? I used the default location.

Comment: *"..is that because wrong location of my class?"*  Most probably.  Always copy/paste error and exception output.  *"I used the default location."*  Which is ..what?  What is in the HTML (the applet tag), as well as the structure of the server - showing the location HTML & the Jar.

Comment: I use xampp to simulate the server,so the default location I mention is "C:\xampp\htdocs",right? but its error shows:"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainFrame.TestFrame.class"

Comment: If you are unable to provide **all** the information I request, I am unable to help.  Don't worry about the file path the server is using.  I want to know about the paths **relative to the server root.**

Comment: The server root path is "C:\xampp\htdocs" exactly.

Comment: I suggest you practice 'How to answer questions' before worrying about more programming.  That skill is vital to programming, or getting help with a program, but you obviously don't possess it.  :(

Comment: Hmm.. I am so sorry. maybe it's I misunderstand your questions. 
I use object tag instead of applet tag,and how I structure them:         

<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
  <param name="codebase" value="."
  <param name="code" value="TestFrame\bin\MainFrame\TestFrame.class" />
  <param name="archive" value="TestFrame.jar" />
  <param name="java_arguments" value="-Djnlp.packEnabled=true"/>
  Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>

Comment: Actually , I used object tag instead of applet tag, I saw on the W3C , it said applet tag didn't support on HTML5 anymore.